# Customize text from console.log()

Tags: javascript

In Ruby, we have `#inspect`, which if overridden will change the output of the `p` function from something like `#<Vector:0x00000000b5e2a8>` to a custom string.

In Javascript, the default object-to-string conversion when using `console.log()` is usually pretty good in Chrome (it's clickable, syntax-highlighted JSON), but for some cases it is not so convenient. Is there a way to change the textual representation in a way similar to Ruby's `#inspect`?

For example, I would like to convert this

```
Vector {x: 0, y: 0, add: function, subtract: function, ...}
```

to simply `Vector(0, 0)`.

Comment: You can override the `toString` method, then `console.log(obj.toString())`.

Comment: You might want to read [Chrome DevTools docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) on using the console.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That seems to be the closest I could get. Both of the above methods require modification of the `console.log()` call though.

Comment: Chrome doesn't use "object-to-string" conversion when using `console.log()`.  I think only IE does that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: You're right, my bad. My only other suggestion would then be something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));`

Comment: Wow, an IE feature I actually prefer over the others.

Comment: It's not very helpful when all you see is `Log: [Object object]`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're right, I didn't think of objects that don't have their own `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom `toString` method:

```
Vector.prototype.toString = function(){ return 'Vector('+this.x+','+this.y+')'; };
console.log(vector+'');
```

Or you could use a custom log function:

```
function log(vector){ console.log('Vector('+vector.x+','+vector.y+')'); }
log(vector);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, you could try `console.dirxml()`. For HTML elements, it prints an expandable tree structure, but for regular JavaScript objects, it creates  a string out of the properties. For example:

```
var testObj = { test: 'value', 'test 2': 'abc' };

console.dirxml(testObj);
```

produces:

```
Object {test: "value", test 2: "abc"}
```

One other suggestion would be to wrap your object in a `JSON.stringify` call, e.g.:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(testObj, null, 4));
```

which produces:

```
{
    "test": "value",
    "test 2": "abc"
}
```

Or drop the second and third parameters to `stringify`, which would give you:

```
{"test":"value","test 2":"abc"}
```